# How to replace an element of an array in a specific way

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm solving a problem with this concept:
It is a classroom, and I have to replace an available seat with a name, but in a specific way: it is replaced in the last row, from right to left. If the classroom is full it will show a message that there are no places available.

I have no idea how to replace an available seat in the order that the problem says.

```
import numpy as np

classroom1 = np.array([["Martha", "Available"], 
                       ["Max", "Anahi"], 
                       ["Available", "Available"], 
                       ["Alexis", "Rigel"]])
```

So far I can replace a seat of my choice manually, but not in the way the problem states.
for example:

```
classroom1[0,1] = "Alex"
print(classroom1)

[["Martha", "Alex"], 
 ["Max", "Anahi"], 
 ["Available", "Available"], 
 ["Alexis", "Rigel"]]
```

But I still can't get an idea of how to solve it according to the problem. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). Even if this isn't homework per se, some of the same advice applies: "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first" and if you don't even know where to start, do some more research first.

Comment: If it helps, did you notice that it wants you to replace the positions from last to first?

Comment: maybe you can use a  for loop with a reversed range to do this. also can you provide a better example of the results/steps you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:-**

```
import numpy as np

classroom1 = np.array([["Martha", "Available"], 
                       ["Max", "Anahi"], 
                       ["Available", "Available"], 
                       ["Alexis", "Rigel"]])
list_of_names=['Yash','Sam','Itachi','Ace']

seats_available=0
for i in range(len(classroom1)):
    for j in range(len(classroom1[0])):
        if classroom1[i][j]=="Available":
            seats_available+=1
#Enter the students in order right to left and starting from the last
count=0
for i in range(len(classroom1)-1,-1,-1):
    for j in range(len(classroom1[0])-1,-1,-1):
        if classroom1[i][j]=="Available":
            if seats_available and count<len(list_of_names):
                classroom1[i][j]=list_of_names[count]
                count+=1
                seats_available-=1
print(classroom1)  #as you can see Ace is not present cause there is no available seats for them when he appeared.
```

**Output:-**

```
[['Martha' 'Itachi']
 ['Max' 'Anahi']
 ['Sam' 'Yash']
 ['Alexis' 'Rigel']]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use reverse indexing or negative indexing to solve this problem. With positive/normal indexing you traverse through an array start through end. But with reverse indexing you use "-" sign with indexes and it traverses in the reverse direction.

consider this example:

```
x = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'])
print(x[2])
print(x[-5])
```

so both these instructions will pring out 'c'
one thing to remember is that in reverse indexing we start from -1 so if you want to print 'g' you would have to pass `x[-1]`

**Now to your original problem:**
you have a 2 dimensional array that means you will have to pass two negative indexes to do the required modification

> classroom[index of subarray][index of element within subarray]

consider another example:

```
classroom1[0,1] = "Alex"
print(classroom1)
[["Martha", "Alex"], 
 ["Max", "Anahi"], 
 ["Available", "Available"], 
 ["Alexis", "Rigel"]]
```

say we want to update the seat at index 0 in array at index 2, so we will have to do reverse indexing as follows:

```
classroom[-2][-2] = "Peter"
[["Martha", "Alex"], 
 ["Max", "Anahi"], 
 ["Peter", "Available"], 
 ["Alexis", "Rigel"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which can scale to huge data by using vectorized functions of numpy.

```
classroom1= np.array([["Martha", "Available"], 
                   ["Max", "Anahi"],
                   ["Available", "Available"],  
             ["Alexis", "Rigel"]])
list_of_names = ['Yash','Sam','Itachi','Ace']
# Get the indices of "Available" seats.
free_seat_idx = np.transpose(np.nonzero(data=="Available"))
# Reverse the "Available" seat indices as they will be replaced from last row.
reversed_fs_idx = np.flip(free_seat_idx, axis=0)

# Fetch the names from list and put them in respective flattened index.
K = classroom1.shape[1]
idx = 0 # index of name list
for val in reversed_fs_idx:
    flat_idx = val[0]*K + val[1]
    np.put(classroom1, flat_idx, list_of_names[idx])
    idx += 1
print(classroom1)
```

Output

```
[['Martha' 'Itachi']
 ['Max' 'Anahi']
 ['Sam' 'Yash']
 ['Alexis' 'Rigel']]
```